# Trigger an event when container enters the screen

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've got an element sliding into the screen left to right. It is wrapped inside a `div` whose `margin-left` changes. This wrapper starts out of screen, on the right. Elements are wrapped this way:

```
<div style="width:1000px; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="wrapper" style="margin-left: 1000px; width: 100000px" > <!-- margin-left dynamically changes -->
    <div class="first">some text</div>
    <div class="second">other text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I trigger an event on second div appearing on the screen?

Comment: here on SO, there are loads of posts talking about how to detect if an element is visible on screen.

Comment: I had a look at them. They use to talk about scrolling or so actually.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [onScreen](http://benpickles.github.io/onScreen/) jQuery plugin. It acts like a pseudo selector, but will allow you to target only matching elements that appear on the page. Like so:

```
$("span:onScreen");
```

Comment: This plugin needs setInterval(), so I can even use .offset().left instead of onScreen. Ty anyway, it can be very useful in other applications

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but, thanks to Matthew R too, I figured out how to use `setInterval()` as part of the solution.

```
    <div class="outer" style="width:1000px; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="wrapper" style="margin-left: 1000px; width: 100000px" >
    <div class="first">some text</div>
    <div class="second">other text</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    var left = $("div.second").offset().left;
    if (left <= $('.outer').width()) { // actually I use a few more conditions
    // do some stuff
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```